# calling an async task in a windows store app?

Tags: c#

I had a working "save reader" that would strip unwanted data out of a winform, then return a list of strings referred to as "items" .

My problem is that when converting this for use with a winstore app; I cannot call an async task, and I need to use one to access the file.

im not 100% sure how to do this, so any help is appreciated; this is what I have so far.
the  public SaveGame(StorageFile file)
    {
        File = promptUser();
}

throws an error, I have tried making the constructor async to, but that throws more errors

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;

namespace save_game_reader
{
class SaveGame
{
    private StorageFile File { get; set; }


    public SaveGame(StorageFile file)
    {
        File = promptUser();
        Task<StorageFile> returnedTaskTResult = promptUser();
        StorageFile intResult = await promptUser();
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> GetAllItems()
    {
        string WholeSaveString = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(File);
        List<string> ToReturn = new List<string>();

        List<string> SplitList = WholeSaveString.Split(new string[] { "data" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
        foreach (string line in SplitList)
        {
            var start = line.IndexOf("value") + 6;
            var end = line.IndexOf("type", start);
            if (end != -1)
            {
                string substring = line.Substring(start, (end - start) - 8);
                if (substring.Length >= 4)
                {
                    ToReturn.Add(substring);
                }
            }
        }
        return ToReturn;
    }
    private async Task<StorageFile> promptUser()
    {
        var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;

        StorageFile sf = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        return sf;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot call an async task"? Windows Store app development certainly supports `async`...

Comment: sorry, ill clarify.

ive written my async tasks, but i dont know how to call them.


so  public SaveGame(StorageFile file)
    {
        File = promptUser();
} throws an error

Comment: Well yes, you need to `await` a `Task<StorageFile>` to get a `StorageFile`... but that's just normal async/await and has nothing to do with it being a Windows Store app. And you won't be able to do that in a constructor...

Comment: my point exactly, i cant call an await in the ctor, so i cant set the list of string.

relevent to winstore apps because i cant just do a file.readAllLines.


i guess the easier questions would be: how can i call an async method from a normal line of code

Comment: What do you mean by "normal line of code"? It feels like you should really just read up on async in general, then look at the problem again. (For example, you could write an async static factory method which would return a `Task<SaveGame>`, and do the `await` in that, calling the constructor with the `StorageFile` itself. But it's not clear whether that would be useful to you.)

Comment: i read up a little. but to return a task<saveGame> i would need to then be able to turn that into a savegame, by awaiting. and then again i would need that class to be async. etc etc.

i cant just call SaveGame sg = await SaveGame

Comment: It sounds like you need to read more, basically. Asynchrony does indeed "infect" your code - but you need to get used to that being the case. Windows Store apps are designed around the notion that nothing long-running is synchronous.

Comment: all i want to do is replace the old functionality of File.ReadAllLines()


sounds silly that i would have to divulge into all this sillyness for it

Comment: You say "sillyness", I say "trying to stop people from doing potentially long-running file IO in the UI thread" - Microsoft is precisely attempting to stop you from reading all of a potentially-huge file while the user has an unresponsive UI. It feels like you'd benefit from reading a good book about Windows Store development to explain *why* async is so important.

Comment: I say sillyness because for the functionality of reading a 2kb text file, stripping some unicode, and returning a list of string; it seems i now have to make 60% of my code asyncronus

Comment: If you don't want to write asynchronous code, you should stop writing Windows Store apps right away. It's one of the corner-stones of the philosophy. You're *really* going to have a bad time unless you embrace asynchrony.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty rare to need to do so, but the typical way to work around constructors in async is to just use a static method:

```
class SaveGame
{
    SaveGame(StorageFile file)
    {
        File = file;
    }

    public async Task<SaveGame> Create()
    {
        return new SaveGame(await promptUser());
    }
}

SaveGame g = await SaveGame.Create();
```

It may be worth it in your case to consider a cleaner separation between UI code and backend code. If something seems weird or difficult to do, it's often a sign of design flaw.

Also, one does not "call an async task". You call an async method and await a Task.

Answer (score -1):

Constructors cannot be async, change your code as follows:

```
public SaveGame()
{}

public async Task Init(Storage file)
{
    File = promptUser();
    Task<StorageFile> returnedTaskTResult = promptUser();
    StorageFile intResult = await promptUser();
}
```

somewhere else in an async method you call it like this:

```
 var save = new SaveGame();
 await save.Init(file);
```

Comment: A static factory method and a private constructor may be more discoverable in the long run _and_ it can be `async`. Forgetting to call generic `Init` methods is always a source of frustration for the poor soul who has to use your code :D

Comment: i think thats getting me on the right track. but to call the await save.Init(file); wouldnt i need to make that class async also? and so on and so on?

Comment: @LiamHaymanTansley Yes, you need to "async all the way up" when using it, in general.

Comment: @Gusdor you're right, but I think that way it is easier for a beginner to see whats going on

Comment: Running initialization code as fire and forget it almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @LiamHaymanTansley I would advise you to make all methods async up to the top of the calling tree, it is easier in the long run. There are other ways to do it, but be prepared to encounter some funny bugs if you dont understand fully what you are doing